# How to open a link in a in-app browser window

Tags: flutter, inappbrowser

I would like to know how to open links in an in-app browser, just like this:

[image: in-app browser]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve that using [flutter_web_browser](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_browser#-readme-tab-) plugin which opens web page in-app in Android chrome tabs style.

Ex:

```
body: new Center(
          child: new RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => openBrowserTab(),
            child: new Text('Open website'),
          ),
        ),


openBrowserTab() async {
    await FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(url: "https://gadgets.ndtv.com/", androidToolbarColor: Colors.deepPurple);
  }
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: it does not work, i am getting this error: Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method openWebPage on channel flutter_web_browser)

Comment: did you run `flutter packages get` and imported said file in your dart file ? Also try doing `flutter clean`.

Comment: @randomUser786 that's the kind of error you get when you just installed the package and haven't restarted the app yet, it hasn't been copied onto the device. Stop the application and start it again.

Comment: flutter_web_browser is not maintained any more

Answer (score 0):

[ChromeSafariBrowser](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/5.x.x/in-app-browsers/chrome-safari-browser) from the  [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) plugin is even a better option