# Flutter launching browser options

Tags: flutter, webview

I am using the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package and trying to launch a URL not in a webview, but also not in the browser app itself, using the `launch()` method.

I do not know what the term to call it actually is, but I would like to get the same view shown in the image below, where you have a bar at the top with the X on the left and the address of the page.

[image: Desired result]

I have tried setting `forceWebView` to true and playing with the other parameters of the method, but can not get to the desired result. (I either end up with a webview with no bar at the top or launching the browser and adding a new tab)

Am I using the wrong package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flutter_web_browser](https://github.com/victorbonnet/flutter_web_browser) plugin for this purpose, like already answered by Darshan in similar question.

[How to open a link in a in-app browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099513/how-to-open-a-link-in-a-in-app-browser-window)