# flutter open browser as separate window (in app pop up)

Tags: flutter

how does oauth (google signin) open a pop-up window & close the window once sign-in is complete?

context:
i would like to open a window as a popup until user completes an action (payment) & close the window once done.

launch like below seems to take the whole screen.

```
launch("http://www.google.com", forceSafariVC: true, forceWebView: true)
```

want something like below & not an inline webview [image: oauth web view]

Edit: saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099513/how-to-open-a-link-in-a-in-app-browser-window). Now trying to find a solution for android.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to accomplish this can be to use the [google_sign_in][1]. The plugin will do all the work. No need to worry about web views. Just install the plugin, then create a `GoogleSignIn` object

```
final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
```

Then call the `signIn` method

```
googleSignIn.signIn();
```

You will find all the set up needed in the documentation
[1]: https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in

Comment: The question is not asking about how to achieve Google Sign In login, it is asking about how to open a WebView as they open in a Pop-up fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package with following helper class.

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class UrlLauncherHelper {

  /// Tries to launch a [url] using a device app.
  /// Supports http, https, sms:, tel:, mailto: and more.
  static launchUrl(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    }
  }

}
```

It also support all kind of other links.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter). It will embed web view inside the app. It will not take the whole screen instead of it will take a portion of your app. You can configure it. It's also support in iOS and android.

The usage is very easy as below:

```dart
 import 'dart:io';

 import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

 class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   WebViewExampleState createState() => WebViewExampleState();
 }

 class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     // Enable virtual display.
     if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return WebView(
       initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: want something like oauth pop-up & not an inline webview.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done with the `webview_flutter` package from pub.dev.

You have to upgrade your build.gradle file in case of android.

Using Hybrid Composition

The mode is currently enabled by default. You should however make sure to set the correct minSdkVersion in android/app/build.gradle if it was previously lower than 19:

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
}}
```

Check out [this link](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/) to get a better understanding.

Here is how you use in the build method inside a widget.

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return WebView(
       initialUrl: 'Url that you would like to open',
     );
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

why not use modal? sth like:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (context) => Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, child: WebView(
   initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
 ););
```