# How to disable options menu in FlutterWebBrowser

Tags: flutter, dart, firefox, flutter-web-browser

I am using the flutter package `flutter_web_browser: ^0.17.1` in my flutter mobile application to open a URL.

As per the documentation, we can set some additional options when we are opening the browser window using customTabsOptions parameter.

`customTabsOptions: CustomTabsOptions(urlBarHidingEnabled: true, showTitle: false)`

I am using firefox as my default browser in my mobile. And when I run the application the URL gets opened using the flutter web browser using firefox.

But there I get a little 3 dotted options menu at the right corner on the title bar. When I touched on it I can see the below menu.

[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsr79.jpg)

Anybody know how to disable this menu so that it does not show when the flutter app opens the URL in the flutter_web_browser?

Thanks in advance.

I looked at the documentation of flutter_web_browser but could not see any option to disable this. All I could see is how to disable the URL bar and the title.

Answer (score 0):

Check my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76577400/13263003). You will need to change plugin to flutter_inappwebview but then you get to hide the url bar and the options menu entirely